# Django HTTP_HOST error from probing hackers, how to disable this 500 error?

Tags: python, django, apache, nginx, http-host

I'm getting an error message sent to my admin email address:

```
ADMIN = ['admin.error.email.here@domain.com'] email address.
```

This error message occurs at a constant rate of around two per minute.

I want to stop all error messages sent to my admin email that are HTTP_HOST errors, but at the same time still receive 500 error messages.  I looked at the documentation and couldn't find any help. I searched on Stack Overflow and only found changing nginx 80 port server config file to contain a header error to a 444 error, so to bypass the 500 error report.  However, this didn't work.

Is there any `setting.py` variable for excluding certain errors? Time is of the essence - like I said, 2 damn emails per minute from some asshole that is desperate to scrape data. It's not a security risk but it is annoying and consuming my monthly email limit from my email host.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First off I didn't test this particular sample yet, but my approach in a similar situation was to write a custom filter for your logging.

For this first write a custom filter:

```
import logging 

class NoAnnoyFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        status_code = getattr(record, 'status_code', None)
        return status_code != 500
```

And then add it to your logging config in your `settings.py`:

```
DEFAULT_LOGGING = {
    ...
    'filters': {
        'no_annoy': {
            '()': 'myproject.utils.NoAnnoyFilter',
        },
    },
    ...
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['no_annoy'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        ...
    },
}
```

You can see some actual samples in the Django code itself: https://github.com/django/django/blob/6709ea4ae91b906742506ac0c42a3a272991001f/django/utils/log.py

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm sure some one else can definitely use that idea... I ended up fixing it by changing what I had in my nginx cofig file,  added this:
  if ($host !~* ^(example.com|www.example.com)$ ) {
      return 444;
  }